# Jquery show() doesn't wait until complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I would like the following sequence:

1. Show div-element with css class yellow
2. run a function witch during ca. 5 seconds
3. remove yellow class and add green css class "state Ok"...

When I run my code, the div-container will not appear until the function has finished. I have not yet observed?

```js
function sleepFor(sleepDuration) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration) { /* do nothing */ }
}



function DoIt() {
    $('#divState').show(100, function() {});
    sleepFor(1000);    
    $("#divState").removeClass("Yellow").addClass("Green");
}
```

```css
div {
    display: none;    
}


div.Green {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #93EEAA;
}

div.Yellow {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #FFEE99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="DoIt()" value="run" />
<div class="Yellow" id="divState">Some Text</div>
```

Comment: You should specify which class you want removed in `removeClass()` call.

Comment: you have display:none on the div, so it wont show until the show() function

Comment: @RaYell: it's still the same result.. :(

Comment: @atmd Yes. But i start with show()... but it doesn't show de div-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to show your element, do this with [`jquery.show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/), you can then delay (if necessary using [`jquery.delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)) and finally you can queue up (using [`jquery.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)) the removal of the "Yellow" class and addition of the "Green" class.

```js
function DoIt() {
    $('#divState').show(100).delay(1000).queue(function(){
          $(this).removeClass("Yellow").addClass("Green");
          $.dequeue(this)
      });
   
}
```

```css
div {
    display: none;    
}


div.Green {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #93EEAA;
}

div.Yellow {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #FFEE99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="DoIt()" value="run" />
<div class="Yellow" id="divState">Some Text</div>
```

Comment: A small point, but consistency should be observed regarding quotes, there are a mix of single and double quotes here (and in the original posters code snippet).

Comment: @HywelRees I agree, but thats tangential to this question

Comment: Perfect. .queue() is what i needed! Thank you very mutch!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing an empty while? In javascript there's a native method to wait for a set amount of time, and you would have find it immediately if you just googled for it.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#divState").removeClass("Yellow").addClass("Green");
},5000);
```

This waits 5000 milliseconds before executing the defined callback. You can then execute this code on your button click like this (assuming you give your button id myButton):

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#divState").removeClass("Yellow").addClass("Green");
    },5000);
});
```

Which is way better than using the html attribute "onclick" as it is an obtrusive practice and thus a bad practice.

Comment: The SleepFor() function is only for demo. In my application, there is another function. (Get data from a SharePoint-List)